# Syntax for redirecting to a named route with existing query parameters and additional ones

Tags: php, laravel

I have a named route I want to redirect to, while attaching the request query parameters leaving them in tact. I tried something like the following, which is throwing an exception: `preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given`

What's the correct way to do this?

```
return redirect($request->query())->route('foo.bar', ['name' => env('NAME')]);
```

This would redirect to the route named `foo.bar` with the parameter set in `env('NAME')` but also pass along all the query parameters in the original request.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-the-request-url

Comment: `fullUrlWithQuery` might be what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$params = array_merge(['name' => env('NAME')], request()->query());
return redirect()->route('route.name', $params);
```

As per the docs:

> The `redirect` function returns a redirect HTTP response, or returns the redirector instance if called with no arguments:

and:

> The `route` function generates a URL for a given named route:

**Reading Material**

- [`redriect`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-redirect)
- [`route`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-route)
- [`request`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-request)

Comment: Yes. It's a named route. You have to be able to pass it an additional parameter. `Missing required parameters for [Route: foo.bar] [URI: foo/{name}].`

Comment: @randombits Well, are you passing that parameter?